# Selecting all data for records based on most recent date

Tags: date, distinct, records

MySQL client version: 5.0.24a

Hey Folks,

I have a table WorkOrders_errors that looks like this:

```
ID      CO  CAR NAME    CAN             BLN         INDATE          MODDATE         EX
66897   461 57  KKLU    KKLUSH9862088   AKLU6013312 1/27/2014 1:00  1/27/2014 1:00  -1
60782   461 57  KKLU    KKLUHB21629300  AKLU6501153 1/26/2014 22:00 1/26/2014 22:00 1
74188   461 57  KKLU    KKLUHB21629300  AKLU6501153 1/27/2014 10:00 1/27/2014 10:00 1
66645   461 57  KKLU    KKLUSH8222080   AKLU6501744 1/26/2014 21:45 1/26/2014 21:45 1
63307   461 126 ZIMU    ZIMUGOA321986   AMFU3037671 1/27/2014 1:15  1/27/2014 1:15  1
65081   461 24  CMDU    CMDUAU1337382   AMFU3043761 1/26/2014 21:30 1/26/2014 21:30 1
72660   461 24  CMDU    CMDUAU1337382   AMFU3043761 1/27/2014 9:30  1/27/2014 9:30  1
```

I need only the records with the most recent MODDATE, ie ID Record 74188, not 60782.
I have tried this a few ways, but without success. Most recently tried

```
SELECT * FROM (
          SELECT * FROM WorkOrders_errors ORDER BY ModDate DESC) as tmp
GROUP BY can
ORDER BY can
```

'ALSO TRIED

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM WorkOrders_errors t1
WHERE t1.Can = (SELECT t2.Can
                 FROM WorkOrders_errors t2
                 WHERE t2.Can = t1.Can
                 ORDER BY t2.Can DESC
                 LIMIT 1)
```

These both seem to take a Huge amount of resources/time. The table only has about 80,000 rows.

Thanks anyone!